# 'assembleAarRelease' not found in root project 'alert'

Tags: flutter, alert

when I use library, image_picker, I have errors Task "'assembleAarRelease' not found in root project 'alert'."
but I remove image_picker in pubspec, the application work well
I need both alert and image_picker

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zmGbU.png)

Comment: can you provide the version of image_picker and your OS?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.